# Error while running on a browser with python cgi

Tags: python, cgi, cgi-bin

I previously had a python script and it works if executed on the commandline or terminal, and now I am trying to run a browser by using the cgi-bin, but it did not work pa wrong with my script?

HTML

```
<html><body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://10.88.25.48/cgi-bin/coba5.py" method="post">
File: <input type="file" name="file"><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Upload"><br/>
</form>
</body></html>
```

Python cgi

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi, os
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
import simplejson as json
import optparse
import sys


form = cgi.FieldStorage()

# A nested FieldStorage instance holds the file
fileitem = form['file']
fn = os.path.basename(fileitem.filename)
data = open('/tmp/upload-cgi/' + fn, 'wb').write(fileitem.file.read())
location_database = open('/home/bioinformatics2/DW/taxo.json', 'r')
database = json.load(location_database)

for line in data: 
 for taxonomy in database:  
  if taxonomy["genus"] == line.replace('\n','') :
   print "Kingdom: %s," % taxonomy['kingdom'],
   print "phylum: %s," % taxonomy['phylum'],
   print "class: %s," % taxonomy['class'],
   print "order: %s," % taxonomy['order'],
   print "family: %s," % taxonomy['family'],
   print "genus: %s" % taxonomy['genus']
   break
 else:
  print ("No found genus on taxanomy")


print """\
Content-Type: text/html\n
<html><body>
<p>%s</p>
</body></html>
""" % (message,)
```

erro on line `for line in data:`
[image]

Comment: `data = open('/tmp/upload-cgi/' + fn, 'wb').write(fileitem.file.read())` add after `data=fileitem.file.read()` so  you try take `on write file` values.  Need set variable or hash for accessing `RAM` values.

Comment: A question : why grab output if you need reading input ?

Comment: @dsgdfg, actually i just call the file that I uploaded to read and then executed and results displayed in html.

Comment: What's the exact result by opening this in the browser? simply a white page? do you get an error message?

Comment: @Rizzit, error that appears as an image I uploaded